# mix javascript and html in a function (jsp)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

As a newbie I am struggling slightly to understand how to 'mix' HTML and Javascript in the same function running in a jsp, and whether this is permitted. If I try and 'mix code' the function does not run.

I have a sql query test which returns whether a cell has a 'photo' designator and, if so, I want to launch webcam code, i.e.

```
<c:if test="${row.ftypeid==3}">
<script>
Camera();
</script>
```

Then the function to start the webcam would be something like -

```
function Camera{
<tr>
<td width="200px"><b>Webcam Photo</b></td>
<td>
<input type="file" name="photo"/>
<br>
<script language="JavaScript">
webcam.set_api_url( 'upload.jsp' );
webcam.set_quality( 90 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
</script>
<br>
<input type=button value="Configure..." onClick="webcam.configure()">&nbsp;
<input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
<br>
```

Conventional procedures in jsp's seem to be only javascript and are completely enclosed in  tags. Is it possible to 'mix' code in this way?

If I try and add the webcam code immediately after the 'if test' (which also displays any existing stored photo) then this seems to 'corrupt' the stored photo which then produces an error (and displays 2 Browse buttons and not 1) if saved.

```
</c:if>
<c:if test="${row.ftypeid==3}">
<input type="file" name="f${row.sequence}">
<tr>
<td width="200px"><b>Webcam Photo</b></td>
<td>
<input type="file" name="photo"/>
<br>
<script language="JavaScript">
webcam.set_api_url( 'upload.jsp' );
```

Thoughts appreciated.

Regards
Active

Comment: Thanks, but if I try and add all the webcam code immediately under the if test then the if test (which also displays any existing photo referenced by the database) seems to be 'corrupted' and the code does not run properly.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not allowed - I think you mean

```
<c:if test="${row.ftypeid==3}">
  <tr>
  <td width="200px"><b>Webcam Photo</b></td>
  <td>
  <input type="file" name="photo"/>
  <br>
  <script language="JavaScript">
  webcam.set_api_url( 'upload.jsp' );
  webcam.set_quality( 90 ); // JPEG quality (1 - 100)
  webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
  document.write( webcam.get_html(320, 240) );
  </script>
  <br>
  <input type=button value="Configure..."   onClick="webcam.configure()">&nbsp;
  <input type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
  <br>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I try and add all the webcam code immediately under the if test then the if test (which also displays any existing photo referenced by the database) seems to be 'corrupted' and the code does not run properly <c:if test="${row.ftypeid==3}">
                                                            <input type="file" name="f${row.sequence}">

Comment: That is impossible to verify without you pasting "view-source" into a [mcve] (use the `<>` snippet editor)